# Querying a table for a minimum based on the largest of a second column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a subquery that has the following

PreviousRateCode, CurrentRateCode, PreviousReportDate, CurrentReportDate, TransactionDate.

The data in my subquery looks like

[image]

How can I query the results below to get the Smallest "RecentDerogMonths" based on the Largest "WorstDerogLevel" ? 
There's an additional column that I omitted that has a customerID, so I need the Smallest "RecentDerogMonths" based on the Largest "WorstDerogLevel" for each customer, and this is a subquery of a larger select, so what I need is something like

```
Select Lowest Months by highest level
From (The result above)
Group by CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
order by WorstDerogLevel desc, RecentDerogMonths asc;
```

If you want all matching rows that meet the condition then use `select top (1) with ties`.

EDIT:

Per customer, you use window functions.  One method uses a subquery, but here is a cool trick:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by customerid order by WorstDerogLevel desc, RecentDerogMonths asc);
```

Comment: Sorry I left out, there's an additional column that I omitted that has a customerID, so I need the Smallest "RecentDerogMonths" based on the Largest "WorstDerogLevel" for each customer.  So what you have is what I need but I'm not sure how to group it since I need the full row.